# Joomla component upgrade with custom code

Tags: joomla, components, customization, upgrade

My client purchased a Joomla component, the comoponent need a customization in both front end and back end.

But his requirment is, custom code in front end and back end to be upgrded while upgrading original component.

Example : I bought a component from a company XYZ and the component name is joomla_events, current latest version is 2.0. I done the customization in the version 2.0. Later on the company releases new version 3.0, If the client upgrade the component from version2.0 to version 3.0 then the custom code in the version 2.0 also updated in version 3.0

Please help to do the custom code upgrade in Joomla component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why editing core files is **never** recommended, because it gets overridden when updated and people then start to have problems.

A simple answer to your question is, you **can't** have the custom code you added into version 2.0 appear in version 3.0.

You will need to re-add the code you added before. Yes, it is pain taking and annoying, however you would have been better in the first place to develop a plugin which could have been used to extend the component and would make upgrading easy. Not only will you have to add your code again, but you will need to thoroughly test it to ensure it works.

Answer (score 0):

check this may be it helps you....

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Managing_Component_Updates_(Component_release_files)